# Radio button groups generated with TcPDF cutting off in adobe reader

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using **TcPDF** to generate a PDF file with radio button groups in it.

When one of these crosses over to the next page the labels remain but the radio button itself disappears. This only happens in Adobe Reader and not in any of my other readers like Firefox / Chrome / Foxit.

```
    $this->ln(5);
    $this->MultiCell(0, 5, '4. Question1', 1, 'L', 1, 1);
    $this->Ln(3);

    $val[$answers['v4']] = true;

    $this->radio('v4', $val['good_verygood']);
    $this->Cell(50, 0, 'Good/very good', 0, 0, 'L', 0);
    $this->Cell(150, 0, '(= luxe)', 0, 1, 'L', 0);

    $this->radio('v4', $val['above_average']);
    $this->Cell(50, 0, 'Above average', 0, 0, 'L', 0);
    $this->Cell(150, 0, '(= modernised)', 0, 1, 'L', 0);

    $this->radio('v4', $val['average']);
    $this->Cell(50, 0, 'Average', 0, 0, 'L', 0);
    $this->Cell(150, 0, '(= on par)', 0, 1, 'L', 0);

    $this->radio('v4', $val['moderate']);
    $this->Cell(50, 0, 'Moderate', 0, 0, 'L', 0);
    $this->Cell(150, 0, '(= not on par)', 0, 1, 'L', 0);

    $this->radio('v4', $val['bad']);
    $this->Cell(50, 0, 'Bad', 0, 0, 'L', 0);
    $this->Cell(150, 0, '(= Needs short term maintenance)', 0, 1, 'L', 0);

    $val[$answers['v4']] = false;
```

I've fixed one of these PDF's quickly by just adding a new page on the one question this happened

```
$this->addPage();
```

But now there are dozens of occurences in multiple PDF's.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution.

Although I do not know why only Adobe has this problem and only if the group of buttons is on a page break, the problem is the name of the radio button.

In my example the buttons are all named v4.
If you name them v4.1 through v4.5 or other unique names, the PDF renders correctly.